# Let $F$ be a field and consider $F[x, y]$. Show that $(x, y)$ is an ideal of $F[x, y]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

> Let $F$ be a field and consider $F[x, y]$. Define $$(x, y) = \{\alpha x + \beta y \ | \alpha, \beta \in F[x, y]\}$$ Show that $(x, y)$ is an ideal of $F[x, y]$.

Here is my attempted proof:

*Proof:* Choose $a, b \in (x, y)$. Then $a = \alpha x + \beta y$ and $b = \xi x + \gamma y$ where $\alpha, \beta, \xi, \gamma \in F[x, y]$. We first show that $(x, y)$ is a subgroup of $F[x, y]$.

Observe that \begin{align*}
a-b &= \alpha x + \beta y - (\xi x + \gamma y) \\
& = \alpha x + \beta y - \xi x - \gamma y \ \ \ \text{ because $F[x, y]$ is an abelian group } \\
&=(\alpha - \xi)x + (\beta - \gamma)y  \ \ \text{ since $F[x, y]$ is an abelian group and a ring} \\
&\in (x, y)
\end{align*}

So $(x, y)$ is a subgroup of $F[x, y]$ (by the subgroup test). Now choose $r \in F[x, y]$ and $a \in (x, y)$, then $a = \alpha x + \beta y$ and 
\begin{align*}r\cdot a &= r \cdot (\alpha x + \beta y) \\
&=r(\alpha x) + r(\beta y) \ \ \text{ by distributivity of $\cdot$ in $F[x, y]$} \\
&= (r\alpha)x +(r\beta)y \ \ \text{ by assosciativity of $\cdot$ in $F[x, y]$} \\
&\in (x, y)
\end{align*}

Similarly one can show that $a \cdot r \in (x, y)$. Thus $(x, y)$ is an ideal of $F[x, y]$. $\square$

---

Firstly is my proof correct?

If so I don't see why we need $F$ to be a field for this to work, I haven't used any facts other than $F[x, y]$ being a ring to prove that $(x, y)$  is an ideal of $F[x, y]$. So if $R$ is a ring, then does it also hold that $(x, y)$ is an ideal in $R[x, y]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof looks very close to correct! You also need to show that $(x,y)$ is nonempty. Indeed, it still works if $F$ is an arbitrary ring.